# How do I extract bold, strike tags using XPATH?

Tags: html, tags, html-agility-pack

I'm writing a small vb application to extract some text using Html Agility Pack.

I need to extract some on tags from the html and not the text nodes.

iParagraph is a collection of nodes containing tags like: strike, u, strong, b, etc. It also contains text nodes. I just needed to skip the first text node because I always know that it will be empty. This is because I'm using CKEditor.

If you need further explanation please ask. I will clarify.

Below is a sample of what I'm trying:

```
Dim paragraph = iParagraphNode.SelectNodes("//body/p and not([contains(text()]))")
```

Comment: If you need more explanation, please ask. I've looked around here: http://xpath.alephzarro.com/content/cheatsheet.html and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/651783/how-do-i-select-only-visible-elements-using-xpath but I can't come up with a good way of selecting the nodes I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is good enough for now:

I just decided to do the following to skip the next node:

```
Dim test = iParagraphNode.SelectNodes.FirstChild.NextSibling.Name = "tag"
```