# Scrolling to element using webdriver?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am still learning and in response to one of my questions: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737321/same-command-works-once-when-executed-but-throws-an-exception-when-executed-a-se?noredirect=1#comment70669855_41737321), I was told to that it might be due because the element in question is not in view.

I looked through the documentation and SO, here was the most relevant answer: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401343/scroll-element-into-view-with-selenium)

You can use the "org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions" class to move to an element:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("my-id"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
## actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

When I try to use the above to scroll to the element:
It says WebElement not defined.

I think this is because I have not imported the relevant module. Can someone point out what I am supposed to import?

Edit:
As pointed out by alecxe, this was java code.

But in the meantime right after trying to figure it out for some time. I have found out the import method for WebElement:

```
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
```

Might help someone like me.

The how of it is also a good lesson, IMO:

Went to: [Documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement)
The

```
class selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement(parent, id_, w3c=False)
```

Need to be separated into the command form mentioned above.

Answer (score 216, accepted):

You are trying to run Java code with Python. In Python/Selenium, the `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions` are reflected in [`ActionChains` class](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_id("my-id")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Or, you can also "scroll into view" via [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView):

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

If you are interested in the differences:

- [scrollIntoView vs moveToElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562095/scrollintoview-vs-movetoelement)

Comment: Ah...there I was for 3 hours trying every method I found on SO and the documentation. I tried the first solution but must have messed it up somehow. I will read the ScrollIntoView Vs moveToElement. Just a quick question, I need the same steps to be done 100 times, I am thinking of using a `for` loop. Would this be a good approach?

Comment: @Sid difficult to say. In certain cases, you can just chain the actions in a loop and then perform once after the loop, but it all depends on a use case. See if it will makes sense to create a separate SO topic for that if help will be needed. Thanks.

Comment: will `move_to_element(ele).perform()` simply scroll to an element, even if the element isn't currently in view?

Comment: @alecxe I don't get how this works (it doesn't with my project) because how can selenium find the object to scroll to if the object isn't visible? Mine is unable to locate the element that I want it to scroll to.

Comment: When I called move_to as you suggested, I got selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: (164, 1297) is out of bounds of viewport width (1366) and height (694). I'm grateful for your answer and I think this IS the way (and also I've learned about ActionChains from your answer), but looks like it needs a bit of improvement. Thanks1

Comment: `find_element_by_id` is now: `element = driver.find_element(By.ID,'my-id')`, as you can see [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-id)

Answer (score 75):

It's not a direct answer on question (its not about `Actions`), but it also allow you to scroll easily to required element:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('some_id')
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

This actually intend to return you coordinates (`x`, `y`) of element on page, but also scroll down right to target element

Comment: Thanks @Andersson I was trying to find the way to do this since you pointed out this might be the problem on the other question. :)

Comment: at first i appended `()` behind, and error ''dict' object is not callable', i checked the element type is `WebElement`. then i removed  `()`  and worked. isn't this a method? I mean, why no `()` need?

Comment: @LeiYang, because location_once_scrolled_into_view is a Python [property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work). Properties takes no arguments (except object instance -self) and should be called without parenthesis

Comment: @Andersson .move_to_element() didn't work for me (I commented on alecxe answer) but yours solution did. THANKS!

Comment: @LeiYang  Here is the source code about `location_once_scrolled_into_view`, to help explain why `()` not need : [selenium/webelement.py at d3b6ad006bd7dbee59f8539d81cee4f06bd81d64 · SeleniumHQ/selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d3b6ad006bd7dbee59f8539d81cee4f06bd81d64/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py)

Comment: It doesn't scroll to the element, if element is not visible, it doesn't scroll to that element and it returns {'x' : 0, 'y': 0}

Answer (score 15):

In addition to `move_to_element()` and `scrollIntoView()` I wanted to pose the following code which attempts to *center* the element in the view:

```
desired_y = (element.size['height'] / 2) + element.location['y']
window_h = driver.execute_script('return window.innerHeight')
window_y = driver.execute_script('return window.pageYOffset')
current_y = (window_h / 2) + window_y
scroll_y_by = desired_y - current_y

driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", scroll_y_by)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, tried other ways but element wasnt clickable. Some time not enought scroll, element was under "Chat box" on bottom, other code too much scroll element was on top  below. menu

Answer (score 8):

Example:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.find_element_by_css_selector(.your_css_selector))
```

This one always works for me for any type of selectors.
There is also the Actions class, but for this case, it is not so reliable.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using driver.execute_script():-

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('myelementid').scrollIntoView();")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another option to scroll page to required element **if element has `"id"` attribute**

If you want to navigate to page and scroll down to element with `@id`, it can be done automatically by adding `#element_id` to URL...

*Example*

Let's say we need to navigate to Selenium Waits documentation and scroll page down to "Implicit Wait" section. We can do

```
driver.get('https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html')
```

and add code for scrolling...OR use

```
driver.get('https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits')
```

to navigate to page AND scroll page automatically to element with `id="implicit-waits"` (`<div class="section" id="implicit-waits">...</div>`)

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to the element by using javascript through the `execute_javascript` method.
For example here is how I do it using SeleniumLibrary on Robot Framework:

```
web_element = self.selib.find_element(locator)
self.selib.execute_javascript(
    "ARGUMENTS",
    web_element,
    "JAVASCRIPT",
    'arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "instant", block: "start", inline: "start"});'
)
```