# Unable to apply filters on search using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am working on scraping data from [owler.com](https://www.owler.com). I have to apply a filter using the advanced search option of the website

[image: THis image]

I'm trying to simulate the task using Selenium in Python but I'm unable to. Here is my code:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_id("advanced-search").click()

        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="advanced-search-popup"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/olr-select-box/div/div/div/select/option[101]').click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='labelName']/option[text()='India']").click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id("advanced-search-results").click()
        `
```

But the above code results in an error

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Any suggestions or input to solve this issue? I also tried to execute JavaScript from Selenium to do the task but it isn't working either.
Adding Screenshot of errors

[image]

Comment: Have you tried waiting for a given page to load before executing the next element.click() call?  It's likely that the element can't be located because the page hasn't completed loading.  For a basic solution you could try time.sleep() for a few seconds, but Selenium also has [a more specialized solution for this problem](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

Comment: I am using this after page is fully loaded , already used time.sleep() function in script but isn't working though.

Comment: Can you provide the `page_source`?  Difficult to diagnose otherwise.

Comment: go on owler.com and sign in . It's home page where advanced search is working.

Comment: it's getting the element but can't able to click the element. the error is shown only after clicking.

Comment: Are you sure? NoSuchElementException should not be caused by a click. Can you add debug output immediately before the click? In this way, if the exception is displayed before the debug output, you will know it is not the click.

Comment: @MikhailRamendik Added screenshot of errors.

Comment: @ZevAverbach Any suggestions?

Comment: man even if you put a time.sleep() for load the page, some time you need put it again between a click and another because when you click on some element is called some functionality that it's not always quickly. just to try introduce a time.sleep(5) between each click and try it

Comment: I haven't had a chance to log in, but seeing your stacktrace I'm wondering whether [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41744403/4386191) would help, since you're getting an "element not visible" error.