# How can I scroll to the bottom of a page with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, vertical-scrolling

I'm trying to use this code to scroll down to the end of a page:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://www.tradingview.com/screener'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

# will give a list of all tickers
tickers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.tv-screener__symbol') 

for index in range(len(tickers)):
    print("Row " + tickers[index].text + " ")
```

But the `while` loop never ends; Selenium continues to try and scroll downward even after it hits the bottom of the page, so the program doesn't proceed. How can I detect that the bottom of the page has been reached so that the code can continue?

Comment: What you could do, is to identify an element at the bottom of the page and call scrollToVisible for that element. Also what language are you using? 

In C# we can do the following 

`public static void ScrollToVisible(this IWebElement element)
        {
            var js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) Browser.Instance.WebDriver;
            js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
        }`

Comment: Hi,  I'm using Python.

Comment: You can call `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)` then.

Comment: That doesn't scroll, I've tried that.

Comment: Have you looked at the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744368/scrolling-to-element-using-webdriver

Comment: What you could do is look for an element at the bottom of the page and use isDispayed method, if it returns true then break out of that while loop.In java we use break; im not sure about python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the ticker, it tells you how many rows (matches) are in the table. So, one option is to compare the number of visible rows to the total number of rows. When you reach that number (of visible rows), you quit the loop.

```
url = 'http://www.tradingview.com/screener'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

selector = '.js-field-total.tv-screener-table__field-value--total'
matches = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
matches = int(matches.text.split()[0])

visible_rows = 0
scrolls = 0

while visible_rows < matches:

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait 10 scrolls before updating row information 
    if scrolls == 10:
        table = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tv-data-table__tbody')
        visible_rows = len(table[1].find_elements_by_tag_name('tr'))
        scrolls = 0

    scrolls += 1

# will give a list of all tickers
tickers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.tv-screener__symbol') 

for index in range(len(tickers)):
   print("Row " + tickers[index].text + " ")
```

**Edit:** Since your setup doesn't seem to allow the previous solution, here's a different approach you can try. The page loads 150 rows at a time. So, instead of counting the number of visible rows, we can use the total matches/rows we're expecting (e.g. 4894) and divide that by 150 to get the number of times we need to scroll. If we scroll at least that many times, in theory, all of the rows should be visible and we can continue with the code.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

url = 'http://www.tradingview.com/screener'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

try:

    selector = '.js-field-total.tv-screener-table__field-value--total'
    condition = EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector))
    matches = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(condition)
    matches = int(matches.text.split()[0])

except (TimeoutException, Exception):
    print ('Problem finding matches, setting default...')
    matches = 4895 # Set default

# The page loads 150 rows at a time; divide matches by
# 150 to determine the number of times we need to scroll;
# add 5 extra scrolls just to be sure
num_loops = int(matches / 150 + 5)

for _ in range(num_loops):

    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    sleep(2) # Pause briefly to allow loading time

# will give a list of all tickers
tickers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.tv-screener__symbol') 

n_tickers = len(tickers)

msg = 'Correct ' if n_tickers == matches else 'Incorrect '
msg += 'number of tickers ({}) found'
print(msg.format(n_tickers))

for index in range(n_tickers):
    print("Row " + tickers[index].text + " ")
```

Comment: wouldn't [`visibility_of_all_elements_located`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html) be enough??

Comment: It would not be enough, no. In order for that to work, you need to know what elements you expect to become visible.  We know that more table rows will load as you scroll, but the table rows have identical attributes. In terms of visibility, selenium won't be able to distinguish between loaded and to-be-loaded table rows. And even though the data is different per row, we can never be sure which order the rows will appear. Thus, the table row elements/data do not provide a sufficient basis for knowing when to stop scrolling.