# Selenium python: can't scroll down an overlay window

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, quora

On Quora, i want to scroll to the bottom of the window i am getting when clicking on view upvoters button, in order to get all upvoters names, the code for scrolling down a standard browser window does not seem to work with an overlay window, any suggestion?
Here is my code for scrolldown function and for clicking on 'View upvoters' Button:

```
def scrolldown(browser):

    src_updated = browser.page_source
    src = ""
    while  src != src_updated:
        src = src_updated
        time.sleep(5)
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        time.sleep(5)
        src_updated = browser.page_source      
    #if (DEBUG): print ("window maximized...")
    return browser

browser.get('https://www.quora.com/What-is-it-like-to-regret-having-children')
for p in browser.find_elements_by_class_name('AnswerVoterListModalLink'):
        time.sleep(5)

        p.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        browser=scrolldown(browser)
        time.sleep(5)
        c=0
        for div in upvoter_name :#browser.find_elements_by_class_name('author_info'):
           list_of_upvoters.append(div.find_element_by_class_name('user').text)
           c+=1
        print("number of upvoters for this answer is :" + str(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can scroll down to the very last element by using something like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41744403/7493063). According to the answer, you can scroll down to the last element with something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='pagedlist_item'][last()]")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Comment: what does mean last element in this case? the last 'view upvotes' button? or the last upvoter username in the list?

Comment: @Youcef : element is a web element here.

Comment: If you check the quora with developer tools, posts are listed like [this](https://lambda.sx/4AK.jpg) and this xpath selects the very last post.

Comment: Sure, you are not supposed to scroll that element, you can choose what element you want.

Comment: Tried this but it did not work for me, i still don't get all upvoters names ( you have to scroll the window down to load more), which the code  could not do