# Navigating a website headless in Chrome using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to figure out how to manipulate a webpage in headless mode using Selenium Python but I keep getting an error message. When I run the below code visible it runs without an issue.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.set_headless(headless=True)
options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'F:\\Python\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")

element = driver.find_element_by_name('q')

element.send_keys('test')

test1 = driver.find_element_by_name('btnK')
test1.click()

print ("Test Completed")
driver.quit()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\URLtest.py", line 154, in <module>
    test1.click()
  File "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.14.0-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.14.0-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.14.0-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium-3.14.0-py3.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: headless chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if the element in question is not in the view port of the browser.

This can be fixed by executing some script or using an `ActionChain` to scroll to the element.

From this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744368/scrolling-to-element-using-webdriver) question:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Comment: This was helpful thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try except to prevent this error from happening.

in `try :` section you put your click command.

in the `except ElementNotVisibleException :` you can set the visibility to visible with a `execute_script` then click.

This should looks like

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible';",Element)
Element.click()
```