# how to fix "element could not be scrolled into view" radio button in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am creating a test for clicking a radio button by clicking "Yes"

radio button code:

```
<div role="group" class="btn-group btn-group-toggle">
 <label class="btn btn-primary">
 <input name=".product2" autocomplete="off" value="true" type="radio"> Yes </label>
```

i already tried:

```
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name*='product2'] [value='true']").click();
```

but it returns an error:

Element `<input name=".product2" type="radio">` could not be scrolled into view

Is there any other selector that i can use to click "Yes"?
or is there a missing details using css selector?

I also tried `find_element_by xpath` by still have the same result.

Comment: if the element is not visible in current window, then first you need to scroll to that location and then you can select the radio button. here is possible solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/41744403/2845389

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this css selector :

```
label.btn.btn-primary input
```

It would be good if you could use WebDriverWait as well.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label.btn.btn-primary input")))

element.click()
```

Approach 2 :

or you can try with ActionChains also :

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label.btn.btn-primary input")))
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()

element.click()
```

Imports would be :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi! this is working thanks :) but with a followup, 
there is a multiple ```class label``` that were constructed with exactly the same radio button and the only different is the ```name``` . how can I click the specific radio button that  I want to click using ```name```? is that possible with css selector? 

for example: 3 radio button with same syntax and the only different is ```name``` 
```.product1``` , ```.product2``` , ```.product3```
how can click the 2nd button ```name='.product2'```?

Comment: yes, it's possible with css selector , `label.btn.btn-primary input[name='.product1']` , you can change name attribute like that. If this answer is helpful to you, Please give me credit by clicking on check mark which is just besides my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@cruisepandey answer seems correct, if it works it is good but if stills not work you can use `javascriptexecutor`

```
element=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[name*='product2'] [value='true']") 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```