# Scrolling to the next element in Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to make a facebook commenting bot in Selenium in Python. I need to scroll down to the button for uploading photos in comments to make the comment and I have this line of code:

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_id('my-id')).perform()
```

When I run it again it scrolls to the same button and I need to scroll to the next one. There's also another issue: this button doesn't have an id.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 5):

So, in order to scroll to multiple elements, you would need to use the `driver.execute_script()` method. If you have your driver and you have your page opened, then you need to isolate the element that you want to navigate to.

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "Whatever xpath you want")
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Once you have this, you will need to get a count of all elements that you want to scroll through. For example, in the [Top 100 Greatest Movies List](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls055592025/) website, I created a method to get the current count of displayed movies

```
def get_movie_count(self):
        return self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='lister-list']//div[contains(@class, 'mode-detail')]").__len__()
```

After that, I created another method for scrolling to my element

```
def scroll_to_element(self, xpath : str):
        element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath)
        self.driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

Once that was done, I created a `for-loop` and scrolled to each element

```
for row in range(movieCount):
    driver.scroll_to_element("//div[@class='lister-list']//div[contains(@class, 'mode-detail')][{0}]".format(row + 1))
```

**UPDATE: Added photo to help**
[image: Sample Program to Scroll through 100 elements]

**Photo Explanation**

In this photo, we have our `WebDriver` class. This is the class that creates our Chrome WebDriver and includes any options that we want. In my case, I did not want to see the "This is being controlled by automation" alert all the time. 
In the `WebDriver` class, I have a method called `wait_displayed` that has `selenium` check the browser's `DOM` for a specific element using `xpath`. If the element exists in the browser's `DOM`, all is good. Otherwise, `python` will raise an `Exception` and let me know that `selenium` could not find my element. In this class, I included the `scroll_to_element` method which allows my chrome driver to find an element on the page and executes `JavaScript` code to scroll to the element that was found.

In the `SampleSite` class, we inherit the `WebDriver` class. This means that my `SampleSite` class can use the methods that display in my `WebDriver` class. ( like `wait_displayed` and `scroll_to_element` ) In the `SampleSite` class, I provide an `optional parameter` in it's `constructor` method. ( `__init__()` ) This optional parameter tells the programmer that, if they want to create an `instance` or `object` of the `SampleSite` class, they need to, either, pass in an existing chrome driver; or, pass in `None` and the `SampleSite` class will open Google Chrome and navigate to our Top 100 Greatest Movies Page. This is the class where I created the `def get_movie_count(self):` method.

In our `main_program.py` file, I imported our `SampleSite` class. After import, I created an instance of our class and called the `get_movie_count` method. Once that method returned my movie count ( 100 ), I created a `for-loop` that scrolls through each of my elements.

Comment: and where should I to declare the "movieCount" variable?

Comment: also i'm getting an error saying that "Instance of 'WebDriver' has no 'scroll_to_element' member"

Comment: The  `def get_movie_count(self):` method should be located in your Page Object. The   `def scroll_to_element(self, xpath : str):` method should be located in your WebDriver Object. The `for-loop` should be located inside of your `main_program.py` file

Comment: i'm new to selenium/python, could you explain it more?

Comment: I can add a photo so you can see a demonstration. One second

Comment: @wojwesoly - I added the photo

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744368/scrolling-to-element-using-webdriver), just use this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(textbox_id)

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element) #Scrolls down until the element is visible
```

Comment: it scrolls to the first post again when ran the second time

Comment: btw is xpath unique to every element or is it like an html class? because if it's unique then this code would continuously scroll to the same element

Comment: Xpath can be  unique or not. When it is not unique, it'll return a collection.

Comment: @Sushil maybe an if checking whether the button is on the page (you don't have to scroll to get to it), something like  is_displayed

Comment: Ok...So since you have multiple elements to scroll to, you can use ```driver.find_elements_by_xpath```instead of ```driver.find_element_by_xpath```. This would return a list of elements with the same xpath. Then, you can loop through these list of elements and call ```driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)``` each time.

Answer (score 0):

please add part of code becasue if you know the aprox height can use:

```
js_scroll = "window.scrollBy(0, 600);"
driver.execute_script(js_scroll)
```

So can try finding the element and simulate press key down:

```
 someElement = driver.find_element_by_id('my-id')
 someElement.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

I can't help you another way with out your code.

Comment: idk what other code to post, it's only logging into facebook and finding the button

Comment: and I don't know the aprox. height beacause sometimes facebook show more comments under a post and sometimes less and the dimension of pictures in posts vary

Comment: may be you can try using:  `someElement.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)` and set a sleep to waiting to load new data on scroll view

Comment: I can but if the button will still be out of the page then the program would either throw an error or just click the previous one again, if I do it like that it also needs to check whether the button is on the page or not

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally you're trying to scroll to a different element. IDs for a page are supposed to be completely unique for a page. If you select by ID and scroll to that element.... scrolling to that same element is going to scroll to that element.

You need to either

- use different selenium selectors to get the collection of buttons and iterate through (Find by XPath, find by class, etc.)
- Select the new or different button by its ID before scrolling to it.

Comment: I was originally going to use selecting by ID but that element doesn't have one

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab all the elements and loop them.

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[aria-label='Attach a photo or video']>i")
for elem in elements:
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elem)
```

Comment: this button doesn't have an id

Comment: What does the html element look like?

Comment: <i class="hu5pjgll m6k467ps sp_EMEH57Vy40m sx_4f33a8"></i>

Comment: it's the button for uploading photos into comments on facebook

Comment: Try this it should loop through all the attach photo.