# Python Selenium select div

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-3.6

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://discord.com/register")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='inputDefault-_djjkz input-cIJ7To' and @type='email']").send_keys(mail)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='inputDefault-_djjkz input-cIJ7To' and @type='text']").send_keys(name)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='inputDefault-_djjkz input-cIJ7To' and @type='password']").send_keys(name)
```

I have a problem.

I do autogenerator accounts and *discord.mail,password,name* work. But with a date, I have problems because they don't have input. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open select *Month*, you can use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'inputMonth')]").click()
```

Then select some month with something like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='react-select-5-option-1']").click()
```

The last number here is the number of options in the list.

Similarly, you can select the *Day* and *Year*.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='react-select-5-option-1']").click()
dont work

Comment: Did you add some wait / delay before the first click and the second? The drop list needs some time to open.

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='react-select-5-option-1']"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)

Comment: Try "//div[@class='css-1yz4bi9-option']" instead and let me know if now it works.

Comment: I'm trying to get the item but when I click this thing hides

Comment: You finally found how to catch these elements?

Comment: yes but I have a problem when I try to copy an item, this window closes

Comment: :) Ask google how to force dev tools into debugging mode (hint F8) this will help you freezing the open dialog etc

Comment: okey work too,
i want 2000 year driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='css-1ba14n5-option']").click()
I do it but it dont work i think because it is necessary to climb down the mouse
how do I do this?

Comment: I didn't check it, but possibly the selector for years will be different

Comment: No I did years, but I can't specify 2000 because it's not visible unless you scroll down with the mouse

Comment: So, you have to scroll the element into view. Done with JavaScript, you know.. And then click it

Comment: how i can do it with selenium?sorry i use selenium 2 days

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744368/scrolling-to-element-using-webdriver and many others. google: selenium python scroll to element

Comment: driver.find_element_by_id("//div[@id='react-select-10-option-5']").click()
why it dont work?

Comment: I need to see this during the debugging, I'm sorry.