# Scraping data-page attributes from web page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape all the products from this site which does not have a pagination button. The products load automatically when you scroll. My script can only scrape the first 40 products. I realized that the products load dynamically in a data-page attribute of the div tag ? ?
I want my script to keep changing the data-page value and load the product but i dont know how to do it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

url = 'https://www.positivepromotions.com/custom-blankets/c/navpp_1001_114/'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.45 Safari/537.36'}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=5000)
data = result.content.decode()
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
## get the category
## get the conbtainer first container
subcategory = soup1.find('h1').text.strip()

itemlist = []
for soup in soup1.find_all('div', class_='row cat-prod-list'):
    for x in range(1,4):
        #for pages in soup.find_all('div', id='categoryProducts', attrs={'data-page': True}):
        for pages in soup.select('div[data-page]', id='categoryProducts'):
            print(pages['data-page'])
            for productList in pages.find_all('div', class_='col-sm-4 col-md-3 cat-prod-container'):
              title = productList.find('a', class_='product-title').text.strip()
              price = productList.find('span', class_='cat-price').text.strip().split('-',1)[0]
              sku = productList.find('div', class_='grid-prod-sku').text.strip()
              #productlist = soup.find_all('div', class_='prod-img-wrap')
              links = productList.find('a', class_='cat-prod-img',href=True)['href']
              image = productList.find('img')['data-src'].split('?',1)[0]

              items = {
                      'Title': title,
                      'Price': price,
                      'Sku': sku,
                      'Category': subcategory,
                      'Link': links,
                      'Image': image
                  }
              itemlist.append(items)
              ##print('Saving : ',title)
              #time.sleep(1)
            
# print total products found
print(len(itemlist))

#df = pd.DataFrame(itemlist)
##print(df.head(5))
#df.to_csv(subcategory+'.csv')
###
```

Comment: Try using `selenium` to load the page and scroll before capturing the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) library. it's very easy to use so don't worry about the implementation.
you need to:

1. install it
2. create your selenium driver (chrome driver preferably)
3. navigate to URL
4. get the data by their XPath (already mentioned in doc.)
5. scroll to the last product to make page load automatically

for the last step use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744368/scrolling-to-element-using-webdriver/41744403)