# Reddit isn't scraping the top comments (python/selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, reddit

Put the entire code into a question, thank you to all that have replied but this issue is super annoying either way help is appreciated!

Context: This code is meant to go onto the top reddit post of the day/week, then screenshot it and once that's done it goes to the comments and screenshots the top comments of said post, the former works but the latter does not.

```
import time,utils,string
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from utils import config

def scrape(post_url):
bot = utils.create_bot(headless=True)
data = {}

try:
    # Load cookies to prevent cookie overlay & other issues
    bot.get('https://www.reddit.com')
    for cookie in config['reddit_cookies'].split('; '):
        cookie_data = cookie.split('=')
        bot.add_cookie({'name':cookie_data[0],'value':cookie_data[1],'domain':'reddit.com'})
    bot.get(post_url)

    # Fetching the post itself, text & screenshot
    post = WebDriverWait(bot, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.Post')))
    post_text = post.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h1').text
    data['post'] = post_text
    post.screenshot('output/post.png')

    # Let comments load
    bot.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)
    
    # Fetching comments & top level comment determinator
    comments = WebDriverWait(bot, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id^=t1_][tabindex]')))
    allowed_style = comments[0].get_attribute("style")
    
    # Filter for top only comments
    NUMBER_OF_COMMENTS = 10
    comments = [comment for comment in comments if comment.get_attribute("style") == allowed_style][:NUMBER_OF_COMMENTS]

    print(' Scraping comments...',end="",flush=True)
    # Save time & resources by only fetching X content
    for i in range(len(comments)):
        try:
            print('.',end="",flush=True)
            # Filter out locked comments (AutoMod) 
            try:
                comments[i].find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.icon.icon-lock_fill')
                continue
            except:
                pass

            # Scrolling to the comment ensures that the profile picture loads
            # Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57630350
            desired_y = (comments[i].size['height'] / 2) + comments[i].location['y']
            window_h = bot.execute_script('return window.innerHeight')
            window_y = bot.execute_script('return window.pageYOffset')
            current_y = (window_h / 2) + window_y
            scroll_y_by = desired_y - current_y

            bot.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, arguments[0]);", scroll_y_by)
            time.sleep(0.2)

            # Getting comment into string
            text = "\n".join([element.text for element in comments[i].find_elements_by_css_selector('.RichTextJSON-root')])

            # Screenshot & save text
            comments[i].screenshot(f'output/{i}.png')
            data[str(i)] = ''.join(filter(lambda c: c in string.printable, text))
        except Exception as e:
            if config['debug']:
                raise e
            pass

    if bot.session_id:
        bot.quit()
    return data
except Exception as e:
    if bot.session_id:
        bot.quit()
    if config['debug']:
        raise e
    return False
```

Comment: Can you provide a url, to be able to recreate your issue?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire It works according with the top reddit posts in a subreddit that week

Comment: @platipus_on_fire For example I ran the bot and the URL was https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/wclubp/what_addiction_is_seen_as_completely_normal_by/

The post itself was screenshotted but the comments were not

Comment: Is this the sort of results you are looking for? https://ibb.co/mCmpdR5
https://ibb.co/G7282fD
https://ibb.co/31KQYWh
https://ibb.co/HnCqZKm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code was fixed by removing code which filters locked comments

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to wait for elements to load in page (be clickable) before locating them. For example, try locating comments with:

```
comments = WebDriverWait(bot, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[id^=t1_][tabindex]')))
```

You will also need to import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

The following code will print out the top 5 comments (using waits and a correct locator):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/wclubp/what_addiction_is_seen_as_completely_normal_by/'


browser.get(url)

elems = WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-testid='post-comment-header']/parent::div")))
for e in elems[:5]:
    print(e.text)
    print('______________')
```

Print out in terminal:

```
level 1
Ill_Animator_4437
·
2 days ago
infinite scrolling in apps
2.4k
Reply
Share
Report
Save
Follow
______________
level 2
AnOperative
·
2 days ago
Why I use reddit on the website not the app, I can tell my self I'm having a 3 page break then I go back to whatever i was doin
37
Reply
Share
Report
Save
Follow
______________
```

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't scrape the comments it skipped it as usual

Comment: I'm not sure about your xpath, didn't test it. Did you also waited comments in this line `comments[i].find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.icon.icon-lock_fill')` ?

Comment: Updated my response with a tangible example.

Comment: I appreciate the example and whilst this does work the code was designed to screenshot not print, I will post the entire code onto the original question

Comment: So then screenshot it after you print it in the terminal, give it a time.sleep(1) for good measure, screenshot it, then move to the next one. The crux of the matter is waiting it and using a correct locator.