# Python Selenium move to element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox() 
driver.maximize_window() 
url = r"https://www.nba.com/stats/players/traditional" 
driver.get(url) 

advanced = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, r'//div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/section[1]/div/nav/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(advanced)
advanced.click()
```

return error is always: element could not be scrolled into view.

I've tried other versions of this code including:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/section[1]/div/nav/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a'))).click()
```

Please help, Thank you already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to accept the cookie consent button and then click on of toggle to expand the dropdown and then select the element.

```
driver.get("https://www.nba.com/stats/players/traditional")
#accept cookie consent
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
time.sleep(1)
#expand
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//div[@class='StatsQuickNavSelector_nav__JzoME']/button)[last()]"))).click()
#click on specific item
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Advanced']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```py
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/section[1]/div/nav/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a')))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)

element.click()
```

To scroll the element into view.
[resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65377801/20443541)

Comment: raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. When executing this code this is the return message I get.  the "Message: " returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

A good study for clean understanding is below

```
    ele= driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="elementid"]')

    action = ActionChains(driver)

    action.move_to_element(ele).click()

    action.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    action.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    action.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    action.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    action.perform()
```